# convert string to single error in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

when I use this code:

```
v = Convert.ToSingle("1035.77219")
```

I get this message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

why? this is not in correct format really?

Comment: double x = 10.52123;
float y = Convert.ToSingle(x);

Comment: but i want convert string to single(not double to single)

Comment: "1035.77219" is what a programmer would write, but high odds that everybody else around you uses a comma instead of a period.  Add System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture so it doesn't matter where you are.  And be sure to complete your Stack Overflow profile so we have some idea where you are located.

Comment: thank you @HansPassant. i add System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possibly due to formatting culture. What locale are you in? Try this:

```
Dim v = Convert.ToSingle("1035.77219", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Console.WriteLine(v)
```

This will read it the right way based on a "." being a decimal point as opposed to a digit separator in some cultures.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
Dim v As Single
v = Convert.ToSingle("1035.77219".Replace(".",","))
```

Comment: I try this. "," is just a seperator. 
in this  ` v = Convert.ToSingle("1,200")` , v is 1200 (not 1.200)

Comment: so we have different decimal separators: I have "." for thousands and "," for decimals and you have the opposite. So swap them in `Replace()`

Comment: sorry I test it and , is for thousands.
look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faab9yks(v=vs.110).aspx